# How to add Diagonastic plugin to IBM Mobile First Project?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, diagnostics

In our project we are using camera feature,how to know user permission granted or not for iphone ?

I tried with using cordova diagnostic method `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getCameraRollAuthorizationStatus()`

To use this method we need to add **`cordova.plugin.diagnostic`** plugin to our project.

I added plugin in config.xml in iphone environmentfile as below

```
 <feature name="Diagnostic">
 <param name="ios-package" value="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic" />
 </feature>
```

After adding this plugin i deployed my project to mobile first server,then the plugin should automatically added to *cordova_plugin.js* but its not happening.

Can any one suggest the steps I followed are correct or not, If not suggest me the steps to add plugin manually in Mobile First project.

Answer (score 0):

You keep asking this question and you keep not understanding each time.

> After adding this plugin i deployed my project to mobile first server,then the plugin should automatically added to cordova_plugin.js but its not happening.

The quoted sentence sentence is completely false.
As mentioned [in this blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) which you have been directed to multiple times, it is *not possible to add Cordova plug-ins to Worklight 6.x - MobileFirst 7.1 Hybrid applications*. You cannot update the cordova_plugin.js file nor will it be updated by the framework. On each build in Studio, this file is **re-generated** - any changes you make to it are Gone.

If you insist on adding a plug-in, you must follow the steps in the blog post, which mention use of Ant to change the file *after* it has been re-generated.

Your options are:

1. Follow the blog post
2. Use Cordova apps in MFPF 7.1, thus allowing you to use Cordova plug-man to add plug-ins with no issue
3. Create a custom Cordova plug-in of your own, based on the specialized instructions provided in the MobileFirst Platform Developer Center. This plug-in should mimic what the plug-in in the question is doing.